# Use Socket to connect to emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I was trying to use SocketServer to setup a server

```
int i =1, PORT = 6666;
ServerSocket server;
Socket client;
try {
    server = new ServerSocket(6666);
    for(;;){
        client = server.accept();//fail in here
        textView.setText("server accept..." + i);
        //new MyHttpServer(client, i, PORT).start();
        i++;
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    //e.printStackTrace();
    textView.setText("Fail...");
}
```

However, the app always stops in `server.accept()`. I have already add internet permission for this app. I don't know why?

Update:
I have found the reason. It is because thread cannot start from an Active instance. I was putted server.accept() in onStart without a thread. Now I open a new Runnable for it, then fixed

Comment: what do you accept this code to do?

Comment: Just trying to open a server to accept a connect from client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be multiple reasons why your application can not start the server. My initial guess would be that you are trying to run the code on an emulator or a device and you already have some other application listening on that port.

You must check/provide the `logcat` trace in order to get to the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think so your app will wait for client with port 6666.

```
 server.accept();// return socket
```

Above code will return socket if client is available.For more details and clearity you can refer these links::

http://www.happygeek.in/socket-programming-in-android

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/socket-programming/